# Split and draw large view android

Tags: android, performance, android-custom-view

I have a need to draw a large view lazily and invalidate part of a view. I got to know that **RenderNode** can solve my problem.(at least it states like that) But I could not use the same. But it's there in the android library. Anyone used rendernode can help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not see @hide annotations to the rendernode class. For some reason android kept that class hidden.
Update:
After i requested to make this class open, they released the same in android 10 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RenderNode